# Proper format of a URL String

Tags: c#

What is a proper URL for accessing a HTTP Server?

```
byte[] vs = new HttpClient().GetBytes("192.168.1.22:8080/myDataCollection.xml");
var bytes = vs;
CrestronConsole.PrintLine("bytes : {0}", bytes);
return bytes.ToString();
```

this gives me an error that the string is not valid.

Comment: maybe you need to add "https://"?

Comment: By the way, `bytes.ToString()` will always return "System.Byte[]"

Answer (score 1):

As Hans says in the comment - the issue is that you aren't providing the protocol in the URL, try:

```
byte[] vs = new HttpClient().GetBytes("https:192.168.1.22:8080/myDataCollection.xml");
```

Also, it's worth noting that the method you've written will not return the XML string. If you want the method to return the XML string you'll need to do it this way (replacing `Default` with the relevant encoding):

```
string xmlString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(vs);
return xmlString;
```